# What does it mean if the write() system call in Solaris returns EACCES?

Tags: solaris

We're having a weird issue in one of our Bamboo plans, which we can't replicate 'locally' (on the same machine, with the same user)

It's failing to copy a file. Here's a truss log:

```
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    + truss cp -f TestEnvironment.zip /mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9/ 
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    execve("/usr/bin/cp", 0xFFBFBB8C, 0xFFBFBBA0)  argc = 4
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    sysinfo(SI_MACHINE, "sun4v", 257)       = 6
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00000000, 32, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xFF3F0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00000000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xFF3A0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00000000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xFF390000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    memcntl(0xFF3B0000, 17560, MC_ADVISE, MADV_WILLNEED, 0, 0) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00000000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xFF380000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    memcntl(0x00010000, 4792, MC_ADVISE, MADV_WILLNEED, 0, 0) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    resolvepath("/usr/lib/ld.so.1", "/lib/ld.so.1", 1023) = 12
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    resolvepath("/usr/bin/cp", "/usr/bin/cp", 1023) = 11
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/usr/bin/cp", 0xFFBFB658)       = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)     Err#2 ENOENT
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/lib/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFADB8)        = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    resolvepath("/lib/libc.so.1", "/lib/libc.so.1", 1023) = 14
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)        = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ALIGN, 3, 0) = 0xFF370000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 1294336, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGN, -1, 0) = 0xFF200000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF200000, 1244845, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_TEXT, 3, 0) = 0xFF200000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF330000, 36029, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_INITDATA, 3, 1245184) = 0xFF330000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF33A000, 1680, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xFF33A000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    munmap(0xFF370000, 32768)           = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    close(3)                    = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    memcntl(0xFF200000, 145936, MC_ADVISE, MADV_WILLNEED, 0, 0) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGN, -1, 0) = 0xFF370000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    getcontext(0xFFBFB4C8)
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, 0xFFBFB4A8)     = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    getpid()                    = 29644 [29643]
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    setustack(0xFF372A88)
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    issetugid()                 = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    brk(0x000288B0)                 = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    brk(0x0002A8B0)                 = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFA958) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    resolvepath("/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 1023) = 33
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    open("/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 9244, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ALIGN, 3, 0) = 0xFF360000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    munmap(0xFF362000, 1052)            = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    close(3)                    = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("TestEnvironment.zip", 0x000286C8)   = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/lib/libsec.so.1", 0xFFBFA188)      = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    resolvepath("/lib/libsec.so.1", "/lib/libsec.so.1", 1023) = 16
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    open("/lib/libsec.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ALIGN, 3, 0) = 0xFF350000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 90112, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGN, -1, 0) = 0xFF1E0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF1E0000, 57581, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_TEXT, 3, 0) = 0xFF1E0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF1F0000, 13281, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_INITDATA, 3, 65536) = 0xFF1F0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF1F4000, 5560, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xFF1F4000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    munmap(0xFF350000, 32768)           = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    close(3)                    = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    memcntl(0xFF1E0000, 14232, MC_ADVISE, MADV_WILLNEED, 0, 0) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/lib/libavl.so.1", 0xFFBFA0A8)      = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    resolvepath("/lib/libavl.so.1", "/lib/libavl.so.1", 1023) = 16
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    open("/lib/libavl.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 14208, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ALIGN, 3, 0) = 0xFF350000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0x00010000, 81920, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGN, -1, 0) = 0xFF1C0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF1C0000, 3276, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_TEXT, 3, 0) = 0xFF1C0000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap(0xFF1D2000, 296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_INITDATA, 3, 8192) = 0xFF1D2000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    munmap(0xFF1C2000, 65536)           = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    munmap(0xFF350000, 14208)           = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    close(3)                    = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    memcntl(0xFF1C0000, 1096, MC_ADVISE, MADV_WILLNEED, 0, 0) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    pathconf("TestEnvironment.zip", _PC_ACL_ENABLED) = 2
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    acl("TestEnvironment.zip", ACE_GETACLCNT, 0, 0x00000000) = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("TestEnvironment.zip", 0xFFBFABC8)   = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    acl("TestEnvironment.zip", ACE_GETACL, 3, 0x000296C8) = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9/", 0x00028630) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9//TestEnvironment.zip", 0x00028630) Err#2 ENOENT
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    open64("TestEnvironment.zip", O_RDONLY)     = 3
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    creat64("/mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9//TestEnvironment.zip", 0777) = 4
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    stat64("/mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9//TestEnvironment.zip", 0x00028630) = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    fstat64(3, 0x000286C8)              = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap64(0x00000000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    write(4, " P K030414\0\b\b\b\0 \ q".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 8388608) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    write(4, "DB ZB8FF [E2F7 kF1FB9BC0".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x01000000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    write(4, " W U \CC gF3 )94 ( R 08C".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x01800000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    write(4, " $EF K v1796 % _A8 X zCD".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:44    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x02000000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    write(4, "01 j9482 3E791 )02B9DBAD".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x02800000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    write(4, "FC w &CE02B2E3 ,1DF9 }8E".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x03000000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    write(4, "01FE zAFD60FF9B7B0 * kAA".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x03800000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    write(4, "B712 Z8D81E4C6F515C3D0F1".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:45    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x04000000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    write(4, "9A j97AB `0FC0C8 ]E1 )C5".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x04800000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    write(4, "1283 z1282DE 60498DB FEF".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x05000000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    write(4, "FC8CDBDCEC (CD93 j9A 61A".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x05800000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    write(4, "8ECC 6BB U93 ~E5B4A2CF g".., 8388608) = 8388608
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    mmap64(0xFE800000, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x06000000) = 0xFE800000
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    write(4, "AD 7BFE9E7F0EFE51686F2 9".., 8388608) Err#13 EACCES
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    brk(0x0002A8B0)                 = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    brk(0x0002C8B0)                 = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    open("/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/C/SUNW_OST_OSLIB.cat", O_RDONLY) Err#2 ENOENT
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    open("/usr/lib/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/SUNW_OST_OSLIB.mo", O_RDONLY) Err#2 ENOENT
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    cp: TestEnvironment.zipwrite(2, " c p :   T e s t E n v i".., 23)   = 23
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    : write(2, " :  ", 2)               = 2
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    Permission deniedwrite(2, " P e r m i s s i o n   d".., 17) = 17
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    write(2, "\n", 1)               = 1
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:46    close(3)                    = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:47    close(4)                    = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:47    munmap(0xFE800000, 8388608)         = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:47    unlink("/mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9//TestEnvironment.zip") = 0
error   14-Dec-2018 14:22:47    _exit(2)
```

The previous command `cp -f TestEnvironment.zip /mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/Solaris_sparc_gcc/` succeeds as well.

```
-bash-3.2$ uname -a
SunOS b2s-sol10spr-4 5.10 Generic_147440-01 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

So, I went to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29032/write-2.html, and it doesn't mention `EACCES`...

What's going on?

Comment: Is the destination directory on NFS? Any unusual permission bits or ACLs on /mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9 ?

Comment: That directory has 777 permissions (dunno much about acl's.

Comment: And that directory is on nfs

Comment: Does `cat TestEnvironment.zip > /mnt/builds/SEN/Touchstone/Maintenance/10.1/solaris10sparc/gcc4_9/TestEnvironment.zip` succeed?

Comment: File locking?  I'd try capturing the NFS traffic and seeing what's going on on the NFS server. After 12 successful 8 MB writes to file descriptor 4, you get an `EACCESS` error from that same file descriptor.  That's really strange, as the only way to get that from the local kernel via [from the Solaris source posted to the internet](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/syscall/rw.c#210) is the `write()` syscall checking for a file lock via the [internal `nbl_conflict()` function](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/fs/nbmlock.c#87).

Comment: This blog entry showing how to list file locks on Solaris 10 seems relevant:  https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/solaris/ListingFileLocks

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that tomorrow. Can file locks be an issue if the target file doesn't exist before the copy?

Comment: @Bwmat I wouldn't have thought so, as what could possibly know to lock the file? Definitely something strange going on. From your truss output, the process successfully writes 96 MB to the same file descriptor that it then gets an `EACCESS` on?!?! Can you create a file larger than 96 MB in that directory with another tool, such as `dd`?  Or as mentioned above, `cat`?

Comment: I didn't try, but I was able to copy the same file to my local windows machine, and then to that nfs folder from there.

Comment: And that file is 'well known', as some other bamboo plans copy it from that location, so maybe someone else is locking it while it's half written?

Comment: @Bwmat *so maybe someone else is locking it while it's half written?*  That's quite possible.  If you have root access to your system, you can place a dtrace probe: `#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s fbt::nbl_conflict:return { printf("%s: %d\n", execname, args[1]);}` and see if you ever get a non-zero return value.  If you do, that's pretty much proof that file locking is involved.  If that's not it, I'd say it's NFS-related, as there's no other way I know of to get `EACCESS` from a file descriptor that you used to be able to write to.

Comment: At first I thought it might be mandatory file locking, but OP said it succeeds locally. So my next theory was that the destination file gets created with a mode that denies write access to the user - maybe by ACLs or a weird umask -  so the writes appear to succeed for awhile because they're cached on the local machine but eventually the NFS server is contacted and says "nope".

Comment: One thing is that I was able to reproduce the issue locally later ('locally' means when I myself was SSH'd into the machine, as opposed to the original occurance when the bamboo daemon on the machine was running a script), so maybe it's a non-deterministic thing.

Comment: Of course it's non-deterministic.  It'd be easy if it were deterministic.  ;-)  Does the error always happen at the same offset?  And can you reproduce the problem on a non-NFS file system?  What version of NFS?  What's the OS of the NFS server?

Comment: I'll have to look into that, might be after the new year.

Answer (score -1):

You did not send your sourcecode, but it seems that you call `mmap()` to get the data you like to write.

I guess that you mapped a region of a file that grants no read access to you.

In order to verify that the problem is not caused by a side effect with `mmap()` you should call

```
dd if=filename of=/dev/null
```

to check whether the problem exists when you definitely only read from the source file.

Comment: I don't have the source, I'm just using the `cp` that's installed on the system.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that, but `cp` mmap()s larger parts of the input file before it calls `write()`. Is there anything with the input file?

Comment: I'm not sure, that file is one that was just created by the bamboo plan, I don't know of anything 'unusual' about it.

Comment: Then you could have a look at the OpenSolaris sources and look for related EACCESS returns. ACLs are e.g. such a case where a file access could cause EACCESS.

Comment: *ACLs are e.g. such a case where a file access could cause EACCESS.* I'm pretty sure the only way ACLs can cause an `EACCESS` return is on `open()` or `openat()`, although I haven't examined the kernel source.  There's no way I can see for ACLs to cause a `write()` to return `EACCESS`, especially **after** a series of successful `write()` calls on that same file descriptor.  Barring something on the NFS server (quite possible, and that's still a complete unknown...), the only way I see in the OpenSolaris source for `write()` to fail on `EACCESS` is for it to run into a file lock.

Comment: If you work using `mmap()`, it is possible that there are further error cases that apply to the "read" access to the mapped region. See my exited answer